# Repairing corrupted file while merging (Using PDFBox Merge)

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I encountered a file which seems to be corrupted. Whenever I open and then close that file on adobe reader then a pop up comes to save that file again without any changes. This made me believe that this file is corrupted.

I am using PDFBox to Merge multiple files. While merging this particular file I am getting below error:

> Error: Expected a long type at offset 8489, instead got ''

I am looking for the way where I can first repair this file and then merge. So, that code doesn’t fail for errors in the file.

PS : If the save this particular file using adobe reader and then try to merge then it got successfully merged.

Comment: Your text "If the save this particular file using adobe reader" is a solution.

Comment: Also make sure you're using the latest version (2.0.24).

Comment: If you alternatively want to know the exact cause, we'd need the file itself for analysis.

Comment: Well, in my experience a need to resave more often stems from errors in the pdf which Adobe Acrobat repairs while loading. I guess this varies with the pdf corpus one has to deal with.  ;)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr i was using 2.0.4 version.  But with version (2.0.24), seems the issues is resolved. thank you very much

Comment: Glad to read that! IMHO you should delete your question. Always use the latest version. If you use maven, then include the maven-versions-plugin so that you know when a new version is released.